# Making pfx from certificates with openssl giving "No certificates matches private key"

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I am unable to work out what is going wrong with this;

```
$ openssl genrsa -out sign.key 4096
$ openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key sign.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out sign.pem
...
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out sign.pfx -inkey sign.key -in sign.pem
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
$ openssl genrsa -out cert.key 4096
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key cert.key -out cert.csr
$ openssl x509 -in cert.csr -out cert.pem -req -signkey sign.key -days 1001
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in cert.pem
No certificate matches private key
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in sign.pem -in cert.pem
No certificate matches private key
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in cert.pem -certfile sign.pem
No certificate matches private key
$ cat sign.pem cert.pem > bundle.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in sign.pem -certfile bundle.pem
No certificate matches private key
$ cat cert.pem sign.pem > bundle.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in sign.pem -certfile bundle.pem
No certificate matches private key
```

I've tried doing this on both windows in git bash and on a linux VM, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cannot just sign a certificate like this and expect it to work, I had to properly sign using ca;

```
$ openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in cert.csr -out cert.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in cert.pem
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

I just grabbed this openssl.cnf file to test with: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/appendix/root-configuration-file.html

Comment: Actually what you can't do is sign a child cert with `x509 -req -signkey $parentkey` because that is only for self-signed (root) certs and changes the key in the cert so it is no longer a proper child cert. **You can use `x509 -req -CA $parentcert -CAkey $parentkey ...`**, although that doesn't have all the features `ca` does; in particular it doesn't put any extensions in the (child) cert unless you specify a file and possibly section on the command line to define them.